# Error while trying to install Solaris in VirtualBox

Tags: solaris, oracle

Hello i tried to install Solaris on virtualbox but after i choose instalation method in grub it is stuck at this
[image: The error im speaking of]

I dont know how to fix it. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Probably not, you haven't told us what you did to get to this state. Perhaps follow https://www.oracle.com/it-infrastructure/technologies/handsonlab-solaris11-on-vm-virtualbox.html or ask for generic information on debugging with virtualbox?

Comment: Why do not install setting all by default?

Comment: all i did is putted iso into virtual machine boot it and after 10 secs it boots the instalaltion wizard (at least should) and this appears.

Comment: @RomeoNinov even after choosing default it displays

Comment: @CrazegiContact, wait few minutes

Comment: What method of installation did you use? Did you use a ready-made VirtualBox image, or did you try to set one up yourself?

Comment: @Kusalananda i used iso from oracle website

Comment: How much memory does your VM have?

Comment: @AndrewHenle 6GB of ram 50GB of storage and 4 cores

Comment: That should be enough [per the install requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60973/glmru.html).  Can you interrupt a GRUB boot menu and add the `-v` verbose option to the kernel boot parameters?  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-2379/fwbme/index.html  FWIW, I suspect there's a good chance it's hanging on IO controller for the root disk - the times I've used Solaris under VirtualBox I've used SCSI for the root disk.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the problem is when the GRUB starts it doesnt show any boot options but just starts counting time 5..3....1 and then it boots up solaris. i tried clicking "e" and "c" but it doesnt work.

Comment: @CrazegiContact Other possibilities could be ESC, shift, or space.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time for some examples.

Comment: @AndrewHenlethanks it worked but im a bit confused where exacly put `-v`